# php source code to PO file generator

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext, multilingual, po-file

I have to convert all my echo/print string from my **php source** code file to **PO file**(for the **language translation**),
is there any batch **convector** available for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I got the answer.

There is a method to extract all the string from  a give source file for a folder.
Here is the link you can check:

- Extract the strings from source code for Translation (for po file)  *[link now dead]*
- Poedit: A cross-platform PO to MO converter and PO file editor *[link now dead]*

Comment: @h00ligan Your link is also now dead.

Comment: SO didn't allow me to edit the comment so I deleted it

Answer (score 4):

How I do this:

- make **gettext** run on your server
- setup a **translation adapter** (for example Zend_Translate with gettext adapter)
- use a good **search** tool to find all strings in your code and **wrap** them with something like $translationObject->translate(). Often the method is wrapped to be called __(). This will be at least partly **handwork** in most cases since you will have various forms of strings which you will maybe also want to split up into shorter units
- install **poEdit** and configure it to parse for 'translate(' or '__('
- send your resulting po-Files to the human translators and instruct them how to use poEdit
- load the translations and generate **mo-files** which are used by the adapter

Answer (score 1):

You need http://www.poedit.net/

> You can use Poedit to scan source code
>   for translatable strings.

Comment: It will search for output inside specified functions, not after an `echo` or `print` as far as I know.

Comment: It also requires a paid licence for US$30 to unlock that functionality it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I do not think such a tool exists. If you find one it will likely be limited in functionality

This is due to ability of php to intermingle with html. It is hard to be able to know what exactly should be included in a particular gettext file.

If you only use "echo" statements to send content to the browser and you are never mixing html and php, then it is pretty simple to write up a script to parse that out.

HTH,
-FT