# How can I automatically extract strings for translation?

Tags: php, html, translation

I wrote a website, with several pages, in PHP and now need it translated to a different language.

I've been searching ages for how I can just automatically extract all the strings and HTML text in my php source code, **manually** translate each, and then insert them back in.

I don't want multi-language support, and I've checked translation solutions such as Translate2, but they all seem to require you to manually go in and replace code.

I'd modify the code myself, but I don't know the language and this needs to be passed on to a translator.

Surely, there's a ready made solution for this?

If not, can anyone recommend some solid regex for string or HTML text searching?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare strings like:

```
$someString = _('Some text that needs to be translated');
```

[PHP Gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php)

[Extract them](http://tutorboy.com/articles/php/extract-the-strings-from-source-code-for-translationfor-po-file.html) to a .po file.

Send them off to a translator, who will translate the strings with [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/).

Once you get your .po back, put it in an appropriately named directory, such as `/your/file/path/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po`

Change the locale in PHP:

```
 setlocale(LC_ALL,  'zh_CN' . '.UTF8') ;
 bindtextdomain('messages', "/your/file/path/");
 textdomain('messages') ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful reply.

I was hoping there'd be something as nice as "pop in unmodified source code and out pops translation file".

From your answer, I found this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465752/php-source-code-to-po-file-generator

I'm pretty sure it's possible, just too difficult. Oh well, I'll go with modifying my hundreds of lines of code to work with gettext then.

Thanks again